# Docker: cannot install openssh-server

Tags: docker, ubuntu, putty

I build the Docker based on Ubuntu 16 and want to allow PuTTY access to the Ubuntu.
I have added the line to the docker file:

```
#Download base image ubuntu 16.04
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Update Software repository
RUN apt-get update

# Install nginx, php-fpm and supervisord from ubuntu repository
RUN apt-get install -y nginx php7.0-fpm supervisor && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get autoclean  -y supervisor
RUN apt-get install openssh-server -y supervisor
```

But when I build the image it gives me

> Step 5/18 : RUN apt-get install openssh-server -y supervisor  --->
>   Running in c9425deece29 Reading package lists... Building dependency
>   tree... Reading state information... E: Unable to locate package
>   openssh-server

How to fix it? My task is: to allow connection from a host (Windows) to the docker container via PuTTY.

Comment: This is [not a programming question](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Dockerfile should work.

```
#Download base image ubuntu 16.04
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Update Software repository
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install openssh-server -y supervisor    

# Install nginx, php-fpm and supervisord from ubuntu repository
RUN apt-get install -y nginx php7.0-fpm supervisor && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get autoclean  -y supervisor
```

There is two thing it seems problematic to me.

- After update I'm always using upgrade to update all packages on my system. It's not necessary but I find it's a good practice
- You are removing ***/var/lib/apt/lists/* *** then you are trying to install openssh-server. apt can't find anything on that path when it need.